# spring-3.x to 4.x migration: test issue

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

My application was written in spring-3.0.4.RELEASE. I am planning to update this version. Now my test classes are failed with the following error.

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

[ERROR] class AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests

Is there any alternative class similar to `"AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests"`. Because I have more than 500 test which implements this class. I need a simple way to migrate these test.

Comment: Any inputs here really appreciated. I am also having the same problem... :(

Comment: Add dependencies to the module.

Comment: If you are still using that class you are in for a a nice migration. As that is using JUnit3 and not JUnit4. You will first have to migrate your tests to use the `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` then migrate your tests to JUnit4 (which means using annotations). Or don't upgrade to Spring 4.

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests` has been replaced with `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.